# При публикации проекта (swift 4.2) в AppStore возникает ошибка при линковке библиотеки libPrinterSDK.a

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Всем доброго времени суток. В проекте на Swift используется SDK для blueTouth принтера Mini Thermal Printer POS-5805DD. В корень проекта добавлена библиотека (идет в комплекте с принтером) libPrinterSDK.a и заголовочный файл PrinterSDK.h, header-файл подключен через bridge, при запуске проекта на реальном устройстве - все работает корректно, никаких ошибок не возникает. Но при попытке собрать проект для выгрузки в AppStore, в самом конце при линовке библиотеки libPrinterSDK.a появляется ошибка:

ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/ivan/Documents/MyProject/PrinterSDK/libPrinterSDK.a(GCDAsyncSocket.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/ivan/Documents/MyProject/PrinterSDK/libPrinterSDK.a' for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Если есть какой-нибудь опыт сборки проекта с файлами libPrinterSDK.a и PrinterSDK.h, буду очень признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден. В настройках проекта BuildSettings/BuildOptions/EnableBitcode надо установить значение NO

Тогда при сборке приложения bitcode не интегрируется и не требуется.

Примечание: правда отсутствие bitcode в сборке потребует отправки новой сборки в AppStore, если выйдет устройство с новой архитектурой, а при наличии bitcode сборку под новую архитектуру создаст ресурс Apple.